# Making the next and previous buttons into arrows

Tags: php, html, css, slideshow

I have a slideshow that has buttons for next and previous (I'm not using jquery) and I need to turn my next and previous buttons into arrows and I have no idea where to start. I couldn't find an answer anywhere else for this either.

CSS

```
.slide {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.slide img {
    display:block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 300px;;
    width: 500px;
}
.slide img:hover + .slide-caption {
    opacity: 1;
}

.slide-title {
    margine:0 0 1rem;
}
.slide-caption {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5 );
    opacity:0;
}
.slide-caption:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
/*div.description {
    color:blue;
}*/

div.prev {
    text-align: left;
}
div.next {
    margin-left:400px;
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

PHP

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $pic_array[$count] = $row['pic_url'];
    $titles[$count] = $row['title'];
    $descriptions[$count] = $row['description'];
    $count++;
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if ($_POST['action'] == 'Previous') {
        $index = $_POST['i'];
        if ($index == 0) {
            $index = count($pic_array) - 1;
            echo "<div class='slide'>
                     <img src= ".$dir.$pic_array[$index]." />
                     <div class='slide-caption'>
                        <h3 class='slide-title'> $titles[$index] </h3>
                        <p> $descriptions[$index] </p>
                     </div>
                  </div>";
        }
        else {
            $index--;
            echo "<div class='slide'>
                     <img src= ".$dir.$pic_array[$index]." />
                     <div class='slide-caption'>
                        <h3 class='slide-title'> $titles[$index] </h3>
                        <p> $descriptions[$index] </p>
                     </div>
                  </div>";
        }
        echo '<form action="gallery.php" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="Previous">
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="Next">';
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='i' value= '$index'' >";

    }
    if ($_POST['action'] == "Next") {
        $index = $_POST['i'];
        if ($index == count($pic_array) - 1) {
            $index = 0;
            echo "<div class='slide'>
                     <img src= ".$dir.$pic_array[$index]." />
                     <div class='slide-caption'>
                        <h3 class='slide-title'> $titles[$index] </h3>
                        <p> $descriptions[$index] </p>
                     </div>
                  </div>";
        }
        else {
            $index++;
            echo "<div class='slide'>
                     <img src= ".$dir.$pic_array[$index]." />
                     <div class='slide-caption'>
                        <h3 class='slide-title'> $titles[$index] </h3>
                        <p> $descriptions[$index] </p>
                     </div>
                  </div>";
        }

        echo '<form action="gallery.php" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="Previous">
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="Next">';
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='i' value= '$index' >";


    }

} else {
    $index = 1;
    echo "<div class='slide'>
            <img src= ".$dir.$pic_array[$index]." />
            <div class='slide-caption'>
                <h3 class='slide-title'> $titles[$index] </h3>
                <p> $descriptions[$index] </p>
            </div>
         </div>";
    echo '<form action="gallery.php" method="post">
        <div class="prev">
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="Previous">
        </div>
        <div class="prev">
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="Next">
        </div>';
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='i' value= '$index' >";
    /*echo "<div class='description'
                <p> $descriptions[$index] </p>
          </div>";*/


}
```

Comment: do a if statement. If page is greater than 1, then echo a <a href="#">Next Page</a> wrapped in an icon for a right arrow.

Comment: and pass the page value in the URL, then do a get request to display that page...

Comment: inputs can be images too, you know...

Comment: at the end of your code you have echo <form action="gallery.php" ... do gallary.php?page=1... then do a $page = null; if ($page = null) {$_REQUEST['page']; } etc to pull that value in to display...

Comment: I'm not exactly following Levi.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a `<form>` for your gallery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to continue to use a `<form>` as the basis of your slideshow, then I suggest using `<button>` instead of `<input type="submit">`. You'll gain a lot more control over what it is you're visually presenting to the user and what is submitted to the sever (since you're using a `<form>`).

By default a `<button>` within a `<form>` will act as a submit button. Buttons allow you to set the content within them which is a lot more flexible than what most inputs will let you do.

The following snippet has a few options.

- Set a `font-icon` or HTML entity as the content.
- Set an image as the content.
- Set an image as the background of the button (you'll have to define dimensions for this to work).

```css
button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: 0;
}
button img {
  display: block;
}
.next {
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  background-image: url( http://placehold.it/100x25 );
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button value="Next">
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-2x"></i>
</button>

<br>

<button value="Next">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x25">
</button>

<br>

<button class="next" value="Next"></button>
```

If you insist on using form inputs as your pager elements, your options will be limited.

Your two main options are [HTML entities](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) or an image.

To use an HTML entity you will have to set it as the `value` of your input.

To use an image you will need to use an image input, `<input type="image" src="path/to/image.jpg">`.

```css
.styled-inputs {
  margin: 2.5rem 0;
}
.styled-inputs input[type="submit"] {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" name="next" value="&raquo;">
<input type="submit" name="next" value="&gt;">
<input type="submit" name="next" value="&rsaquo;">
<input type="submit" name="next" value="&rarr;">
<input type="submit" name="next" value="&xrarr;">
<input type="submit" name="next" value="&xrArr;">
<input type="image" src="http://placehold.it/25x25">

<div class="styled-inputs">
  
  <input type="submit" name="next" value="&raquo;">
  <input type="submit" name="next" value="&gt;">
  <input type="submit" name="next" value="&rsaquo;">
  <input type="submit" name="next" value="&rarr;">
  <input type="submit" name="next" value="&xrarr;">
  <input type="submit" name="next" value="&xrArr;">
  <input type="image" src="http://placehold.it/25x25">
  
</div>
```

The issue with using an HTML entity is that you can no longer do an `if ( $_POST[ 'action' ] == 'Next' )` as you've changed the value from `Next` to an HTML entity.

Using `<input type="image">` will require a slightly different check than you are doing now. Instead of having two submit inputs with the same name and checking their value, you'd have to set a different name for each and check if one is set or not as image inputs do not allow you to assign a value.

As you can see a `<button>` is the way to go if you continue using `<form>` to drive your slideshow.

Comment: Okay I almost have it working, but I need to only have it appear when I hover over it. I used similar css for the hovering over the caption but the buttons only appear when I hover over the actual buttons but not the picture or caption itself.

Comment: .slide {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.slide img {
    display:block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 300px;;
    width: 500px;
}
.slide img:hover + .slide-caption {
    opacity: 1;
}
.slide-title {
    margine:0 0 1rem;
}
.slide-caption {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 16px;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5 );
    opacity:0;
}
.slide-caption:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

Comment: .previous {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 16px;
    opacity:0;
    background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5);


}
.previous:hover {
    opacity:1;
}

.slide img:hover + .previous {
    opacity: 1;
}

.slide-caption:hover + .previous {
    opacity: 1;
}
.next {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 16px;
    opacity: 0;
    right:0;
    background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5);

}
.next:hover {
    opacity:1;
}

.slide img:hover + .next {
    opacity: 1;
}

.slide-caption:hover + .next {
    opacity: 1;
}

Comment: echo "<div class='slide'>
            <img src= ".$dir.$pic_array[$index]." />
            <div class='slide-caption'>
                <h3 class='slide-title'> $titles[$index] </h3>
                <p> $descriptions[$index] </p>
            </div>";

Comment: echo "<form action='gallery.php' method='post'>
            <div class='previous'>
            <button value='Previous' name='action'>
                <i class='fa fa-arrow-left fa-2x'></i>
            </button>
            </div>
            <div class='next'>
            <button value='Next' name='action'>
                <i class='fa fa-arrow-right fa-2x'></i>
            </button>
            </div>
            </div>
            <br>

Comment: Please stop posting all your code in the comments. Add it to your post. When you do need to post **small** pieces of code wrap it with a single backtick `\``. That way it's more legible. What you're asking now is a separate question from the current post.

Comment: Please look at your CSS. You're asking to show the previous/next arrows when the image is hovered. Is your CSS doing that? You're attempting to show the previous/next arrows when you hover the slide's caption container and previous or next is a sibling of the caption container. Target  the `.slide` element itself. Something like `.slide:hover .previous, .slide:hover .next { opacity: 1; }`. You could simplify that selector by adding an additional class of `.pager` to `.previous` and `.next`, i.e. `<div class="pager previous"></div>`. Then you could use `.slide:hover .pager { opacity: 1; }`.

Comment: You should accept answers once they've been answered. This will help you get your answers answered in the future.